# Is Bauer–Hanson’s result “there is a topos where the Dedekind reals are countable” novel?

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionism

Last year, Andrej Bauer [gave a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CBFUojXoq4&list=FLuLR2oAJOXHh0nBVDDuj3Lg&index=24&t=71s) showing that there is a topos in which the set of Dedekind reals is (sub)countable, and thus, you cannot prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable without LEM. He claims in [this abstract](https://researchseminars.org/talk/ToposInstituteColloquium/57/) that this was an open problem. However, [it was already known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410703/subcountability/410755?_gl=1*8q3akn*_ga*NDIwNzk0NDg2LjE2NDA5NzU5Njg.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY5MjgwMzczMC4yOTguMS4xNjkyODA0MzQzLjAuMC4w#410755) that it is consistent with CZF that every set (and in particular, the Dedekind reals) is subcountable. So is Bauer's and Hanson's result actually new?

Also note that Bauer's and Hanson's result is not yet published, but it should supposedly be published soon according to [Bauer's blog](https://math.andrej.com/).

Edit: Thanks to the answers by Andrej Bauer and James Hanson, I have realized my biggest misunderstanding. I for some reason implicitly thought subcountability and countability are equivalent, but this is not the case in the intuitionist setting. Thus, the consistency of the Dedekind reals being subcountable does not yield that it is consistent that the Dedekind reals are countable.

Something else several others pointed out is that CZF is a generally weaker system than "ZFC without choice or LEM". So, even if the question were to be solved in CZF, this wouldn't mean the question "Can the real numbers be shown uncountable without excluded middle and without the axiom of choice?" was really settled. Bauer's and Hanson's topos construction gives a negative answer in the setting of higher-order intuitionist logic (and in IZF as per Hanson's comment).

Thanks again to everyone for sharing your input!

Comment: @SamHopkins It is not that at all. I am trying to understand the difference of these results.

Comment: @SamHopkins I think you're making too much of an assumption.

Comment: Perhaps it would be sensible to wait for the paper to be made available, or to contact the authors directly if you don't wish to wait. It's difficult to make comments on work that is unpublished.

Comment: Indeed, I _believe_ that the result is novel (someone as prolific as Bauer surely is aware of the consistency of CZF with every set being subcountable), but I don't see _how_ it is novel. From my naive understanding, it appears to me that it was already known to be unprovable in constructive math that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, no?

Comment: I think the subtlety here is that there are many different things "constructive mathematics" could mean. CZF is quite *weak*, to my understanding; I think(?) that the intuitionistic set theory true across elementary toposes is much stronger, and so a CZF-consistency result does not yield a topos-existence result. But I'm not an expert here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks. So then do you think that the CZF result is insufficient to claim that the uncountability of the Dedekind reals is unprovable without LEM?

Comment: @Anon I would never$^*$ make a claim of that form under *any* circumstances, precisely because of the ambiguity mentioned in my previous comment; "unprovable without X" is meaningless unless I also say what I *am* allowed to use. $$$$ $^*$OK fine, I might, but I'd feel bad about it afterwards.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, thanks for clarifying for me. I guess I was most confused about Bauer's statement "Can the real numbers be shown uncountable without excluded middle and without the axiom of choice? An answer has not been found so far" in the abstract. But the question is, I suppose, ambiguous to begin with.

Comment: In light of the discussion above and below, I retract my comment that this question had bad intent, but I still think it could've been phrased more delicately.

Comment: There is nothing subtle going on, except: If every subcountable set is countable then excluded middle follows. Perhaps this is what's confusing @Anon, namely that subcountability does not imply countability. Also, in the realizability topos on infinite-time Turing machines there is an injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$, but there is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. BTW, we're in the final stages of writing the paper, you may hold your breath.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I actually believe the implicit theory of toposes is weaker than $\mathsf{CZF}$. My understanding is that $\mathsf{CZF}$ is comparable to $\mathsf{KP}$ and toposes are comparable to $\mathsf{HA}^\omega$ (which IIRC is actually equiconsistent with $\mathsf{HA}$).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453312/is-the-potential-countability-of-mathbbr-a-novel-result#comment1172632_453312), please use, e.g., *believe* `*believe*`, not $\textit{believe}$ `$\textit{believe}$`.  The latter doesn't fit well with surrounding text.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Actually sorry, I was slightly wrong. I think toposes are comparable to intuitionistic high-order arithemtic (with power sets). $\mathsf{HA}^\omega$ typically means arithmetic with function types added, but this is intuitionistically weaker than adding power sets.

Comment: @LSpice I cleaned it up.

Comment: This sounds very interesting, but at the same time, I have to admit, not all too surprising. If you study ZF and the failures of AC, you quickly learn how different the orderings of cardinals via injections and surjections can get. So weakening your setup even further to break "countable" from its many equivalent forms would easily result in these notions being separate, as well as with the level of the reals.

Comment: Can I ask that you add more context to *the title*? There is no shortage of cranks on the internet trying to soapbox their nonsense about how $\Bbb R$ is countable, and I'd hate to give them an excuse based on merely this title and none of the context of the body.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am not sure what a more appropriate title would be. If you know one, I can change it to that (or you are welcome to change it for me if you would prefer).

Comment: @Anon: The goal here is to clarify that (1) this is a consistency result, and (2) it is a consistency result relative to some weak constructive theory (but it would be helpful to mention it in the title, rather than just saying "in constructive mathematics", since plenty of cranks haven't got the foggiest idea of what that mean and would give it their own reading).

Comment: @Anon Regarding your edit, my impression is that the standard tripos-to-topos construction actually can be used to build a model of IZF, which would mean that our construction establishes that IZF cannot prove that the Dedekind reals are uncountable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree that the title could probably be more precise. That said I don't think weakness of the ambient theory is the right way to think about the result. The topos in our paper can in a syntactic sense interpret anything the ambient model of ZFC can.

Comment: As a classically minded person myself, I'd say a good classical way to understand the result is this: Intuitionistic theories have an implicit notion of 'effectivity' or 'computability.' The Dedekind reals are in some sense the 'computable' reals, and the MacNeille reals are more like arbitrarily specified reals.

Comment: I’ve edited the title to be more precise, following @AsafKaragila’s suggestion and further discussion; I hope OP feels it still fits their original intent well enough, and that James and Andrej agree it accurately (though very crudely) summarises their work in question.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter, this title is much more descriptive and much less prone to abuse by cranks.

Comment: @JamesHanson Thanks for pointing that out! I added the comment about IZF to my edit.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks for the improved title! The title you wrote accurately reflects my original intent indeed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Please allow me to list some basic observations that might clear up things. I work constructively (without excluded middle) and without the axiom of choice, and assuming powersets are available.

##### Which reals?

There are three standard constructions of reals, which differ constructively:

- **Cauchy reals** $\mathbb{R}_c$ are constructed as a quotient of rational Cauchy sequences.
- **Dedekind reals** $\mathbb{R}_d$ are constrcuted as (double-sided) Dedekind cuts of rationals.
- **MacNeille reals** $\mathbb{R}_m$ are constructed as a certain weaker version of Dedekind cuts of rationals.

We have $\mathbb{R}_c \subseteq \mathbb{R}_d \subseteq \mathbb{R}_m$, where all three inclusions might be proper.

The MacNeille reals fail to satisfy $0 < x \lor x < 1$, which makes them less useful.

Without countable choice, the Cauchy reals are not nice, either. One cannot even show that they are Cauchy-complete.

So the canonical construction for reals is by Dedekind cuts, so most constructive mathematics is done with $\mathbb{R}_d$. (Note also that $\mathbb{R}_c = \mathbb{R}_d$ in the presence of countable choice.)

#### Countability and subcountability

The definition of countability that works well is: $A$ is **countable** if there is a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to 1 + A$. When $A$ is inhabited this is equivalent to having a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to A$.

A set $A$ is **subcountable** if there is $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and a surjection $S \to A$. In particular, every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is subcountable.

A set $A$ is **uncountable** if it is not countable. A stronger property is **sequence-avoiding**: for every sequence $\mathbb{N} \to A$ there is an element of $A$ that is not a term of the sequence.

**Theorem:** *The MacNeille reals are sequence-avoiding, thus uncountable.*

*Proof.* See [A constructive Knaster–Tarski proof of the uncountability of the reals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07366) by Ingo Blechschmidt and Matthias Hutzler. $\Box$

**Theorem:** *$\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ are sequence-avoiding, thus uncountable.*

*Proof.* Cantor's diagonal method is constructive. Given $f : \mathbb{N} \to \lbrace 0, 1\rbrace^\mathbb{N}$, the sequence $n \mapsto 1 - f(n)(n)$ differs from $f(n)$ in the $n$-th place. Similarly, given $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, the set $\lbrace n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \notin f(n) \rbrace$ differs from $f(n)$ at $n$.
$\Box$

Caveats:

1. Constructively the set of binary sequences $\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace^\mathbb{N}$, the powerset $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, and the reals (of any kind) *cannot* be shown to be in bijective correspondence.
2. It cannot be shown constructively that every real has a digit expansion, so we cannot carry out the diagonal method on $\mathbb{R}$ that way. (This is also a good reason for *not* teaching uncountability of the reals using decimal expansions. The method of nested intervals is to be preferred, as it works with either excluded middle or countable choice.)

**Theorem:** *If excluded middle holds then $\mathbb{R}_c = \mathbb{R}_d = \mathbb{R}_m$, and they are all sequence-avoiding, thus uncountable.*

*Proof.* See notes from your freshman year in analysis. $\Box$

**Theorem:** *If countable choice holds then $\mathbb{R}_c = \mathbb{R}_d$ and they are both sequence-avoiding, thus uncountable.*

*Proof.* See for example Bishop's book “Foundations of constructive analysis" (1967, Section 2.2), where the method of nested intervals is employed, using countable choice. $\Box$

Contrary to classical mathematics, subcountability has very little to do with countability, apart from the obvious observation that every countable set is subcountable.

**Theorem:** *There is a topos in which there is an injection $\mathbb{R}_d \to \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}_d$ is sequence-avoiding, so there is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_d$.*

*Proof.* This happens in the realizability topos on Joel Hamkins's infinite-time Turing machines. I have not actually written this down, but the embedding is done much the same way as the embedding $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ in [An injection from the Baire space to natural numbers](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0960129513000406). The idea is that infinite-time Turing machines can compute from any code of a rational Cauchy sequence converging to $x$ a canonical such code. $\Box$

It has also been known since at least the 1980's that in the effective topos $\mathbb{R}_d$ is subcountable and sequence-avoiding.

#### Further remarks about “sizes” of sets

When you enter the constructive world, you should leave classical ideas about size behind.

**Theorem:** *Suppose the following principle holds: if there are injections $A \to B$ and $B \to A$ then there is a bijection $A \to B$. Then excluded middle holds.*

*Proof.* See [Cantor–Bernstein implies Excluded Middle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09193) by Chad Brown and Cécilia Pradic. $\Box$

**Theorem:** *Suppose the following principle holds: every subset of a finite set is finite. Then excluded middle holds.*

*Proof.* See the Anger stage of [Five stages of accepting constructive mathematics](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/bull/1556). $\Box$

**Theorem:** *If every subcountable set is countable and Markov principle holds, then excluded middle holds.*

*Proof.* See Proposition 2.6 of [Every metric space is separable in function realizability](https://doi.org/10.23638/LMCS-15%282%3A14%292019) by Andrej Bauer and Andrew Swan. $\Box$

Comment: You mention "Bishop's book on constructive analysis", but he seems to have [at least 2](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/publications-search?query=au%3ABishop+pt%3Abook+ti%3A%22constructive+analysis%22).  Did you mean "Foundations of constructive analysis" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0221878))?

Comment: The theorem giving the subcountability of the Dedekind reals and citing Hamkins' work, is the "no surjection" the other way around? Also, in the second of the two caveats, with the nested intervals method, it mentions _with_ excluded middle and countable choice: is this meant to be _without_ excluded middle?

Comment: @LSpice: I improved the reference, although it is generally known that countable choice suffices for uncountability of reals, so that's by no means the only reference available.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing things up! I don't know why I was thinking subcountable and countable are equivalent. This answer really helped.

Answer (score 25):

In the topos we construct in our paper there is a surjection/epimorphism from the natural numbers to the Dedekind reals. In the model of CZF you mention (and in the effective topos) the Dedekind reals are subcountable, meaning that there is a surjection from *a subset* of the natural numbers to the Dedekind reals. Externally this subset has non-trivial computational complexity (corresponding roughly to the set of Turing indices of total computable functions), so the situation in the new topos is more special.

One way to see how this is subtle is that it is known by a result of Blechschmidt and Hutzler, in [A constructive Knaster–Tarski proof of the uncountability of the reals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07366v1), that the MacNeille reals are uncountable in any topos. Also Cantor's diagonal argument and similar give that Cantor space and Baire space (and therefore the set of *irrational* Dedekind reals) are always uncountable, even when they are also subcountable. (And to clarify, I mean uncountable in the positive, constructive sense that given any sequence of elements one can construct an element not on the list.)

There's also some really bizarre specific cases in our topos: The (Dedekind) interval $[0,1]$ is countable, the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$ is countable, the circle $S^1$ is countable, but $(S^1)^\omega$ is uncountable (by Lawvere's fixed-point theorem). Also the Cauchy reals are uncountable despite the fact that the Cauchy reals in this topos are externally isomorphic to the Dedekind reals. And indeed there is internally a 'sub-two-to-one' map from the Cauchy reals to the Dedekind reals, so the Dedekind reals are one application of 'countable choice for sub-pairs' from being uncountable.

Incidentally given that the construction is a modification of the standard construction of the effective topos, it should be a fairly trivial matter to modify it to give a construction of a model of IZF (and therefore also of CZF) in which the Dedekind reals are countable.

Comment: I guess I should be slightly careful with the word 'construct' when referring to the topos itself in that the proof relies on a strengthened form of Brouwer's fixed-point theorem, which is famously non-constructive. Although we were told by Blechschmidt that known conservativity results imply that the consistency result itself must go through in IZF.

Comment: I'd say we construct the topos allright, but we don't construct a Miller sequence (by which the topos is parameterized), because its existence is non-constructive.

Comment: Well technically doesn't the tripos-to-topos construction (typically) use a whole model of ZFC? Isn't that a tad bit less constructive than one measly little application of weak Kőnig's lemma?

Answer (score 18):

A first big difference between Brauer & Hansen's result and the one you are talking about is that  CZF is a predicative theory (it doesn't have power set/power object) so consistency with CZF doesn't say anything about what is possible in a topos. The internal logic of toposes has more to do with IZF, or rather something like IZF with bounded replacement.
For example:

- It's not clear that the Dedekind reals are even definable in CZF. (though it seems it is possible - see the [comment by David Roberts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453312/is-bauer-hanson-s-result-there-is-a-topos-where-the-dedekind-reals-are-countabl/453340#comment1172885_453313) below).
- The usual Cantor diagonal argument shows that it is not consistent (say in IZF or in a topos) that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is subcountable (as in "is a subquotient of $\mathbb{N}$"). But $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ doesn't exist in CZF so it's fine, but it shows that it is inconsistent with IZF that every object is subcountable.

**Edit:** However, as pointed out by Andrej in the comments [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453312/is-the-potential-countability-of-mathbbr-a-novel-result#comment1172650_453313) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453312/is-the-potential-countability-of-mathbbr-a-novel-result#comment1172674_453313) — that's not where the new contribution of their result lies: Independently of the result cited in the OP. It was already known that the Dedekind reals can be sub-countable in a topos (and that it is consistent with IZF) — this holds in the effective topos. So depending on which classically equivalent definition of "countable" and of "the reals" you are using, it was already known that "You cannot prove he reals are uncountable in IZF(that is ZFC without AC and LEM)". The new contribution lies in the difference between "countable" which means being a quotient of the natural numbers and "subcountable" which means "being a quotient of a subobjects of the natural numbers" or equivalently, "being a subset of a countable set". Without LEM there is a big difference between these two notions! In intuitionistic mathematics, a subset can be much more complicated that the set itself. For example, a subset of a finite set doesn't have to be finite.

Comment: To clarify, my understanding is that the topos construction is joint work between Bauer and Hanson together.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've corrected!

Comment: I see, so in some sense, CZF removes more than just choice and LEM. So when Bauer says "Can the real numbers be shown uncountable without excluded middle and without the axiom of choice? An answer has not been found so far", the CZF result did not give an answer because it was even weaker than the stated  question. But now Bauer's and Hanson's topos result resolves the question (I think).

Comment: Absolutely. "ZFC without choice and LEM" is IZF (of course up to details as "ZFC without xyz" doesn't mean anything), which is considerably stronger than CZF.

Comment: This answer fails to call out the OP's unspoken false assumption,  namely that somehow subcountability implies countability.  Constructively we cannot show that an injection from $A \to B$ with $A$ inhabited yields a surjection $B \to A$ (in any variation of constructive mathematics, because we would get excluded middle). All this talk about predicativity, and flavors of constructive mathematics, etc., is a red herring.

Comment: @Andrej Thanks for pointing this out, I should have mentioned it but I still believe the difference between predicative and intuitionist is the main point: Was it know before that it is consistent in IZF/topos logic that the real are subcountable? To me the OP was aware of the distinction (because different name!) but considered that it was maybe not important enough to be the novelty in your result... But maybe I'm just projecting my own opinion here. And in any case, you are right that it is good to spell it out!

Comment: Yes, it was known that there is a topos in which $\mathbb{R}$ is subcountable (a quotient of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$), namely the effective topos.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry, In that case I withdraw my objection and will edit my answer!

Comment: I edited to do some proofreading.  In particular, I assume that the references to "the real" and "the natural number" were supposed to be "the [set of] reals" and "the [set of] natural numbers", and edited accordingly.  If I am mangling usual jargon thereby, then I apologise. I also tried to link to @AndrejBauer's comment that you referenced, but I wasn't sure which one you meant, so I just linked both in this thread (although there is also [another comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1172649) above). I hope this was correct.

Comment: @SimonHenry: The usual Cantor's diagonal argument shows that there is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \to P(\mathbb{N})$. How do you get from that we cannot show subcountability of $P(\mathbb{N})$?

Comment: @SimonHenry: Excuse me for complaining so much, but it is not true that one "needs LEM to show that the reals are uncountable". Countable choice also suffices.

Comment: something like this can be said everytime one says that something can't be proved "without xyz" though... but I've removed that unfortunate phrasing, because you are right - it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Martin Escardo pointed out elsewhere that CZF does actually construct the Dedekind reals as a set: 
Crosilla, L., Ishihara, H. and Schuster, P. (2005) “On constructing completions,” The Journal of Symbolic Logic. Cambridge University Press, 70(3), pp. 969–978. doi: https://10.2178/jsl/1122038923.

Comment: Thanks, that is very surprising - I need to look at this...

Comment: The construction of the Dedekind reals in CZF is a classic application of subset collection. With only exponentiation instead of subset collection, it is not possible.

Comment: @AndrejBauer As for the question from the 23th, that should also be just taking a $f\colon S\to {\mathcal P}{\mathbb N}$, looking at $D=\{n\in {\mathbb N}\mid n\in S\setminus f(n)\}$ and finding $f(k)=D$ implies $k\in D\leftrightarrow k\notin D$. It's stated for ECTS+recursion in the [Aczel/Rathjen book draft](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/book.pdf) p.79 but I've also seen it elsewhere. That set theory context has Replacement and uses Separation in a way where the subset $D\in{\mathcal P}{\mathbb N}$ is broader than as with $2^{\mathbb N}$ where subcountability remains permitted.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K: Beautiful, thanks you. Here's one way to reduce your argument to the usual Cantor's theorem: given $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, there is a surjection $h : P\mathbb{N} \to PS$, namely $h(B) = B \cap S$. if we had a surjection $S \to P\mathbb{N}$, then $h \circ f : S \to PS$ would be a surjection also, contradicting Cantor's theorem.

Comment: @SimonHenry: In your Edit you state: it was already known that "You cannot prove the reals are uncountable in IZF(that is ZFC without AC and LEM)". No, this was not known at all, not to my knowledge. Where did you get this from? What was known is: "You cannot prove the reals are not subcountable" (because they are subcountable in the effective topos) – but that is a very different statement.

Comment: @AndrejBauer no this time Idisagree. I clearly said "depending which classically equivalent definition of countable and of the reals you are using". Subcountable is a very reasonable classicaly equivalent way to define what countable mean. Sorry I had missed your question above!

Answer (score 4):

Against my better judgement, I would answer your question in the negative.

My motivation is that even rather strong classical theories cannot prove that

"there is no injection from Cantor space (or: the real numbers using your favourite representation, or: Baire space) to the natural numbers" (NIN)

The relevant results due to Dag Normann and myself may be found here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.07560

In particular, the above NIN is not provable in Z$_2^\omega$+QF-AC$^{0,1}$, which consists of

1. Kohlenbach's base theory of higher-order RM (RCA$_0^\omega$, which is classical).
2. Functionals S$_k^2$ that decide all $\Pi_k^1$-formulas (for any $k$)
3. countable choice for quantifier-free formulas (QF-AC$^{0,1}$)

As suggested by its notation, the system Z$_2^\omega$ proves the same second-order sentences as Z$_2$, i.e. second-order arithmetic.

Comment: Excuse me, but what does the Cantor space have to do with the Dedekind reals?

Comment: And furthermore, how are classical theories relevant here? With excluded middle you can just show, using the usual proof, that the reals are uncountable.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Firstly, the same 'hardness' result holds for Cantor space, Baire space, and the reals with your favourite representation.  I have clarified this in my answer.  Secondly, which of the probably hundreds of "usual" proofs are you talking about?  You need "a lot" of excluded middle/comprehension/... to prove NIN.

Comment: "There is injection $X \to \mathbb{N}$" is *not* countability of X. That is *subcountability*. Countability (for inhabited $X$) is "there is a surjection $  \mathbb{N}\to X$". Please see my answer where I clarify these notions. They seem to be creating some confusion.